# php search results table doesn't behave like original table

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, search, web

i have a table of employees that i need to be able to perform the search function on , but when i implemented the function i was forced to create another page for the result so i copied the populate table code from the original page and it worked fine except that i added buttons in the outer 3 columns of the table and these only work with the original table (works perfectly there )  , but when i try to use the buttons in the results page i get a blank page with only my html+css design on it without any output , eventhough i have an output specified for each case -it's like the php code isn't even running-

note : 
the post requests aren't the problem cuz when they were the problem the page didn't actually do anything  at all (which is what expected from it at that point).

i'll add a link with poth my pages php files for anyone to see and i'll be available if some more informations is needed :)

https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/17wWScailbySmSpUPCuHDdgIur74VAp1d?usp=sharing

the employee.php file hase the same code except it calls every employee instead of some of them .

i tried adding the code of employee.php that relates to this one erlier but someone said that it was not needed.

the form calling this code exists in the file employee.php and it

```
<form action="searchEmp.php" method="post"> 
    <input type="text" name="search" value="">
    <input type="submit" name="search-btn" value="Search">
</form>
```

and this is the code from the employee search (that has the problem) ::

```
    if(isset($_POST['search-btn'])) {
        //  echo 'search btn pressed ';

         $search = mysqli_real_escape_string($con , $_POST['search']);
        // echo 'looking for : ' . $search ; 
         $sql =  "select * from employees where emp_fname like '%$search%' or emp_lname like '%$search%' or emp_email like '%$search%' or idNumber = '$search' or emp_phonenumber = '$search' " ; 
         $result = mysqli_query($con , $sql);
        //     echo 'result : ' . $result ; 
         $queryResult  = mysqli_num_rows($result);
        //   echo 'result : ' . $queryResult; 
         if($queryResult > 0 ){
        //    echo 'more than 0 results...' ;
        echo "<form action='".$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']."' method='post'>";
        echo '<div class="table_" align="center">' ; 
        echo '<table style="font-family: arial; font-size: 15px;" border="1" cellpadding="1" align="center">';
        echo '<tr bgcolor="#009933">
                <th><b>ID</b></th>
                <th><b>First Name</b></th>
                <th><b>Last Name</b></th>
                <th><b>Phone Number</b></th>
                <th><b>Email</b></th>
                <th><b>Salary</b></th>
                <th><b>Status</b></th>
               </tr>';
            $i = 0 ;
        while($row =mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
            echo '<tr>' ;

            echo '<td>'.'<input type="text" name="id'.$i.'" value="'.$row['emp_id'].'"/> '.'</td>';


            echo '<td>'.'<input type="text" name="fname'.$i.'" value="'.$row['emp_fname'].'" />'.'</td>';


            echo '<td>'.'<input type="text" name="lname'.$i.'" value="'.$row['emp_lname'].'" />'.'</td>';


            echo '<td>'.'<input type="text" name="phone_number'.$i.'" value="'.$row['emp_phonenumber'].'" >'.'</td>';


            echo '<td>'.'<input type="text" name="email'.$i.'" value="'.$row['emp_email'].'"/> '.'</td>';


            echo '<td>'.'<input type="text" name="salary'.$i.'" value="'.$row['emp_salary'].'"/> '.'</td>';


            echo '<td>'.'<input type="text" name="status'.$i.'" value="'.$row['emp_status'].'" />'.'</td>';

            echo '<td> <input type="submit" name="update_btn'.$i.'" value="update"/> ';

            echo '<td> <input type="submit" name="profile_btn'.$i.'" value="profile"/> ';

            if(isset($_POST['profile_btn'.$i])){
                // the profile btn has been pressed..
                ob_end_clean(); 
               $id = $_POST['id'.$i] ; 
               header("Location: profile.php?id=".$id) ;
               exit(); 
              //  printf("Location : " .$i) ;
               }


            if(isset($_POST['update_btn'.$i])){
                if(isset($_POST['check'.$i])){
                    $id = $_POST['id'.$i];
                    $fname  = $_POST['fname'.$i] ;
                    $lname = $_POST['lname'.$i];
                    $phone_number =  $_POST['phone_number'.$i];
                    $email = $_POST['email'.$i];
                    $salary =$_POST['salary'.$i] ;
                    $status =$_POST['status'.$i];

                    $updateStatus = "update employees set emp_fname ='$fname' , emp_lname='$lname' ,emp_phonenumber='$phone_number', emp_email='$email', emp_salary='$salary', emp_status='$status' WHERE emp_id = '$id' " ;

                    $qry = mysqli_query($con,$updateStatus);
                    if(!$qry){
                        echo 'failed to update...';
                    }else{
                        header("Location: employee.php");
                    }

                }else{
                    echo'please activate the update modification options using the tick' ;
                }
            }

            echo  '</td>';
            echo '<td>';
            echo ' <input type="submit" name="delete'.$i.'" value="delete"/> ';
            if(isset($_POST['delete'.$i])){
             if($_POST['check'.$i]){

                 $id = $_POST['id'.$i];

                 $delete = "delete from employees where emp_id = '$id'";
                 $query = mysqli_query($con,$delete);
                 if(!$query){
                     echo'delete failed';
                 }else{
                     header("Location: employee.php");
                 }

             }else{
            echo'please activate the check modify the data' ;
             } 
            }
            echo '</td>';

            echo '<td>' ;
            echo '<input type="Checkbox" name="check'.$i.'"  />' ;
            echo '</td>' ;

            echo'</tr>';
            $i++;
        }   

            echo '</table>';
            echo '</div>' ;
            echo '</form>' ;

         } else{
            echo 'no results..' ; 
         } 
    }
```

the table buttons in the search page is not working . (last three columns of the table -buttons- aren't working corectly).

Comment: post your code here, the relevant one.

Comment: ok i'll edit the post :)

Comment: The relevant only please

Comment: modified again :)

Comment: This code is terrible in a multitude of ways. The mixture of creating output and processing form data that was send to the script alone is … yuck. Whether this script part does anything depends on whether `$_POST['search-btn']` exists ... but I don’t see a form field of that name anywhere in the code you have shown, so where is that supposed to come from?

Comment: i already did when the two gentlemens told me before you :)

Comment: @CBroe hi i'm an android developer and this is my first time ever workin on a web project  can you please give a couple of points to keep in mind while working on web development so my code won't be an absolute disaster.

Comment: Well for starters, try to stick to the [IPO model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPO_model) as much as possible.

Comment: thanks i'll look it up and try to implement it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution:**

Just add a hidden input field to the form on **results page**.

```
<input type="hidden" name="search-btn" value="Search">
```

Now since you arent processing that field, the value doesn't matter.

**Explaination:**

On the results page, on the very first line you are checking for a `POST` field `search-btn` and if it is not found, the whole code block gets skipped.

Now your search result page seems to work because the form from where the request is posted **has** the input field named `search-btn` so it works fine.

But when you try to click the button from the search result the data is posted **from** itself **to** itself, ie. No additional data is addded. And since you don't have the field named `search-btn` in **that** form, the code is skipping the logic block you wrote, and just showing you a blank page.

Comment: yes but usually it works fine when finding results and when there's no result my problem is that the buttons on the displayed records are not working.

Comment: Updated my answer.

Comment: Welcome, FYI, your code has vast areas of improvement, once you get the grasp of the language, you should focus on improving your code. Regards.

Comment: sure i''m planning to do that :) ..

can you recomend some pointers that will help research and learn how to improve my code ?!? :)

Comment: Glad to help, Look into 1. Untangle your database logic (model) from your php logic (controllers) and html generation logic(view). 2. Learn how to use inline php. 3. Validate & Sanitize the incoming data before consuming it (POST, GET , SERVER) 4. Use tokens to prevent CSRF 5. Use prepared statements and parameterized queries. etc...